# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getTokenToEthInputPrice')

Tags: web3js, blockchain, ether, uniswap, web3-providers

I have an issue with getEthToTokenInputPrice
Here is part of my code that is not working.

```js
const web3_utils = require('web3-utils')
const Web3 = require('web3')

const ETH_AMOUNT = web3_utils.toWei('1', 'Ether')
const exchangeContract = new web3.eth.contract(EXCHANGE_ABI, EXCHANGE_ADDRESS);
const daiAmount = await exchangeContract.methods.getEthToTokenInputPrice(ETH_AMOUNT).call()
```

But I am getting this error:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getTokenToEthInputPrice')
```

From this documentation https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V1/reference/exchange
it seems right but it's failing on getTokenToEthInputPrice.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think your contract is not properly deployed...are you trying to access an existing one or creating a new one ?

Comment: I am accessing an existing one. What do you mean that it is not properly deployed @DanielWeigel

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the contract does not contain the method you are using. `getEthToTokenInputPrice` is a method only available on uniswap v1's [exchange contract](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v1/reference/exchange).

For example, the exchange for DAI and Eth is on [0x2a1530C4C41db0B0b2bB646CB5Eb1A67b7158667](https://etherscan.io/address/0x2a1530C4C41db0B0b2bB646CB5Eb1A67b7158667#readContract). Your code should work fine with it.

Hope that helps, happy coding.

Comment: Don't copy & paste the same answer. The system will flag them as duplicates. If you think the questions are the same you can flag them as duplicates.

Comment: Sorry didn't know this. I was just being lazy, now it is modified to fit this question.